# Adding icon to my application issues

Tags: java, swing, icons, toolkit

I want to change the icon of my application.  `system.gif` is in current directory. `getDefaultToolkit()` is not working. `getToolkit()` is working but another minimized window is also open. Other components are Swing components.

```
Toolkit theKit = jtfMainFrame.getDefaultToolkit();
Image icon = theKit.getImage("system.gif");
```

Answer (score 4):

To get an icon for an app.

1. Add it to the Jar and use `Class.getResource("/system.gif")` to obtain an URL to it.  File objects will generally not work for such an 'application resource'.
2. To load the image, use `ImageIO.read(URL)`.  This is a blocking method that will ensure the image is entirely loaded before proceeding.  It will also throw informative exceptions if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Can you please find your shift key and use it at the start of every sentence?  Can you spell all 3 letters of the word 'you'?  Can you show some effort and ask a specific question?  Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt?  SO is not a help-desk, nor a code factory.

Comment: Sorry sir.i tried  Toolkit theKit = jtfMainFrame.getDefaultToolkit();
Image icon = theKit.ImageIO.read("system.gif"); which is showing error

Comment: Well, normally it would pay to show ***the error***, though that code is so broken that the answer is obvious to me.  But to help you help yourself, I'll suggest this.  Type "ImageIO.read(URL)" into your favorite search engine and follow the first link to the JavaDocs that you see.  Then read them carefully and try again.  As an aside, programming is not magic, and requires a lot of consulting the docs.  Bookmark the latest docs. in your browser.